# "No Suggestions" in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, class, netbeans6.8, phpdoc

For a few days now I'm using NetBeans 6.8 for doing PHP work. 
But even if a class-file is included and the methods are public and there's phpDoc used, NetBeans everytime shows "No Suggestions" in the window.

E.g. I type

```
$user->
```

and press CTRL+Space, I do expect all the methods and variables but there aren't shown any. ideas?

Comment: Are you using a NetBeans project or just browsing files? NetBeans will parse your project if you have one created but will not spider just general files even if they're included I believe.

Comment: I do use it for a whole Project but I don't use the debugging (Zend, xdebug) is it perhaps because of that?

Comment: I figured the problem out a bit more precisely, please see my new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996711/how-to-get-suggestions-in-netbeans-for-included-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $foo = new Bar();
```

When ctrl click on Bar (or right click -> Go to definition) you should go the the Bar class.
*To the __construct() to be precise.*

If netbeans doenst jump, that means it doesn't know where the Bar class is defined.
   $foo->   `ctrl+space`
 Would then say "No suggestions"

In your case:

```
$user = new User();
$user->
```

If $user is a parameter:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 */
 function myFunction($user) {
    $user->
```

check that you got `/**` and not just `/*`

If $user is retrieved via a function:

```
 /**
  * @return User
  */
  function getUser() {
     // impl
  }
  $user = getUser();
  $user->
```

Comment: It doens't work for included files, please see my new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996711/how-to-get-suggestions-in-netbeans-for-included-files

Answer (score 1):

Make sure netbeans do know what is stored in `$user`. Every method should have proper @return annotation with either scalar name/array or class name.

If user class is named User, your user getter should look like

```
/**
@return User
*/
function getUser() {
    //some code
    return $user; //instance of User
}
```

Comment: I tried it with @return, but it doesn't had any effect it seems as if NetBeans just ignores classes from other files, since furthermore there aren't shown any Variables.

Comment: you seem to be talking about the docs; I believe the issue is not that there are no docs, but that NetBeans can't find the methods.