# How to get suggestions in NetBeans for included files

Tags: php, class, include, netbeans6.8, phpdoc

i have a problem to get suggestions for classes which are included in included files.

E.g. content of file 'Header.php' is:

```
//File 'Header.php':
include('User.php'); //Class file
```

When I now include the Header.php in my file 'Example.php', i do not get any suggestions:

```
//File 'Example.php':
include('Header.php');
User::
```

After typing User:: I exspect Methods and Vars of class User as suggestions, but there arent any. If I would include 'User.php' directly in my 'Example.php' it works, but that doesn't help me. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me, but all the files have to be included in a Project file.  You can't just open random files and include them.  Also, if it's lagging, try pressing Crtl+Space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***static*** keyword to declare your methods and vars in class. Then Netbeans (definitely in NB 6.9.1) will show suggestions like ClassName::...
But this one solution is not for all cases...